# how to generate wsdl client in intelij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jaxb, wsdl

this is the most simplified version of my problem I could generate.

I got a web service :

```
@WebService()
public class Service {
  @WebMethod
  public IsLoggedInResponse IsLoggedIn() {
    return new IsLoggedInResponse();
  }
}
```

this is the class I return:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class IsLoggedInResponse {
    private boolean isLoggedIn;

    public IsLoggedInResponse(boolean isLoggedIn) {
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }

    public IsLoggedInResponse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @XmlElement
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return isLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setLoggedIn(boolean isLoggedIn) {
        this.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

this is the xsd generated when pressing right click on the webserivce and generate wsdl code from java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://webservice.pubsale.com/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.pubsale.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="IsLoggedIn" type="tns:IsLoggedIn"/>

  <xs:element name="IsLoggedInResponse" type="tns:IsLoggedInResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="IsLoggedInResponse" type="tns:IsLoggedInResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="IsLoggedIn">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="IsLoggedInResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="tns:isLoggedInResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="isLoggedInResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="loggedIn" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

notice isLoggedInResponse is created twice. why? how do I stop it?

Comment: It appears to be caused by having an overloaded constructor for `IsLoggedInResponse`.  Do you want two constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright found the problem seems for each webmethod  'METHODNAME' JAXB creates in the schema a complex type named METHODNAMEResponse

my solution was to to add "DTO" to all my requests/responses.

could also change my method name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://webservice.pubsale.com/" xmlns:tns="http://webservice.pubsale.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="IsLoggedIn" type="tns:IsLoggedIn"/>

  <xs:element name="IsLoggedInResponse" type="tns:IsLoggedInResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="isLoggedInResponseDTO" type="tns:isLoggedInResponseDTO"/>

  <xs:complexType name="IsLoggedIn">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="IsLoggedInResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="tns:isLoggedInResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```